# To delete data in the sqlite database older than certain number of days

Tags: android

I did search in the internet for the relevant information and implemented. But somehow, it doesn't work at my implementation. I like to delete the data older than certain number of days.
When I save the data, the date format is saved as follow.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,d MMM yyyy,HH:mm:ss");
Date today = (Date) Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
String receiveDate = df.format(today);
```

I like to delete the data older than number of days and implemented as follow

```
    public boolean delete_oldData(int numofdays){
            String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM " + SQLITE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TIMEINSTANCE +  " <= date('now','-" + numofdays + " day')";
            Log.d("Delete Query: ", deleteQuery);            
            myDb.execSQL(deleteQuery);         
            return true;
     }
```

But it doesn't delete any data. What could be wrong?

Comment: you save your date as a string, you need to either save it as a long or parse the date in your query

Comment: agree with njzk2, it is much easier to manage long values as timestamps

Comment: All my implementation are set with the String format. If I change to long, I have to change a lot. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -numofdays);
String str = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Replace " <= date('now','-" + numofdays + " day')" with " <= '"+ str + "'".

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I tried, it doesn't work. Now I delete row by row after the date comparison for each row.

Comment: Can you try that with < insteadof <=? Also, it would be easier to use Android SQLiteDatabase delete method.